# How does metalcraft work in Two-Headed-Giant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

I'm playing Two-Headed-Giant and have a creature with metalcraft. I control 1 artifact and my teammate controls 2. Does my creature's metalcraft ability 'trigger'?

I know metalcraft says "if ***you*** control 3 or more artifacts", but since THG obscures the idea between player and team so much I'm having trouble figuring our what 'you' refers to in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a word, no.

**Players do not share control of permanents in Two-Head Giant.**

In addition, **with the exception of "attacking player" and "defending player," all of the referents in THG are the same as regular Magic.** "You" is you. "Target player" and "target opponent" refer to a single player. "Your opponents" are two players, individually.

Here are the relevant comp rules:

> 810.5. With the exception of life total and poison counters, a team’s resources (cards in hand, mana,    and so on) are not shared in the
> Two-Headed Giant variant. Teammates may review each other’s    hands
> and discuss strategies at any time. Teammates can’t manipulate each
> other’s cards or    permanents.
>
> 810.7b Any one-shot effect that refers to the “defending player” refers to one specific defending    player, not to both of the
> defending players. The controller of the effect chooses which one the
> spell or ability refers to at the time the effect is applied. The same
> is true for any one-shot effect    that refers to the “attacking
> player.”
>
> Any characteristic-defining ability that refers to the " “defending player” refers to one specific    defending player, not to
> both of the defending players. The controller of the object with the
> characteristic-defining ability chooses which one the ability refers
> to at the time the nonactive    players become defending players.
>
> All other cases in which the “defending player” is referred to actually refer to both defending    players. If the reference involves
> a positive comparison (such as asking whether the defending    player
> controls an Island) or a relative comparison (such as asking whether
> you control more    creatures than the defending player), it gets only
> one answer. This answer is “yes” if either    defending player in the
> comparison would return a “yes” answer if compared individually. If
> the    reference involves a negative comparison (such as asking
> whether the defending player controls    no black permanents), it also
> gets only one answer. This answer is “yes” if performing the
> analogous positive comparison would return a “no” answer. The same is
> true for all other cases    that refer to the “attacking player.”