# What happens if you cast a card that says "Target Opponent" in Two Headed Giant?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-two-headed-giant

Let's say I'm playing a game of 2HG, and I cast [Tribute To Hunger](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=227064), which reads:

> Target opponent sacrifices a creature. You gain life equal to that
>   creature's toughness.

Do I get to pick which opponent has to sac a creature, or do I cast it at them (being my two opponents) and they pick?

Comment: I think this is answered by the existing question [How does metalcraft work in Two-Headed-Giant?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6861/how-does-metalcraft-work-in-two-headed-giant) Summary: your opponents still count as two separate players, so you pick which one to target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A Two-Headed Giant game has 4 players, two of which are your opponents. When you cast a spell, you choose a legal target, in this case one of your opponents.

> 810.1. Two-Headed Giant games are played with two teams of two players each.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you do have to choose.

Since Two-Headed Giant has 2 heads, you have to choose a TARGET head.

And by opponent, you should read "any player not on your team".